# Imagesc equivalent in C?

Tags: c, image, matlab

Hi I am working with a matrix of 448*448 elements of real(signed) data and wanted to display it as grayscale image in C as i did in MATLAB using `imagesc`. Can anyone tell me which is the fastest and easiest library or code to display the grayscale image from the matrix in C?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like software recommendation which is off-topic these days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/). Although not C but C++, that should be able to do what you want. Unless of course C++ is a big nono for you. Whether or not it is fastest or easiest is not something I dare to claim. You'll have to figure that out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at [openCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) libs. These libs are quite good. It has both c and C++ interface.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick has a native C API if you want to avoid OpenCV: [MagickWand](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php). If you want better low-level capabilities you can try [MagickCore](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php). The ConstituteImage function supplied with MagickCore  sounds like it would do what you like.

Answer (score 0):

As shobhonk suggested, take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org), a computer vision and image processing library that works with C and C++. To accomplish something similar to **imagesc** in C++, I use the functions [imread and imshow](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html) or alternatively I load the data in a [Mat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) structure and I display it with imshow.