# How to Display Image of a 2D RGB Matrix at C++

Tags: c++, rgb, cimg

Firstly, I should say that I am not familiar with C++. My purpose is that. There is a function at Matlab *imagesc*. With a given input of 2d matrix that has double values of RGB it shows a RGB image. I want same at C++ and found that: [Imagesc equivalent in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744744/imagesc-equivalent-in-c) it says that I can use CImg.

However I couldn't do it at CImg (I couldn't find anything at documentation and google)

**My question: How can I show a RGB image with a given 2D matrix at CImg?**

**PS:** Other libraries that CImg is welcome. I just need a simple and basic solution for my purpose.

**EDIT 1:** I have a Win7 Operating System and I use Visual Studio 2010.

**EDIT 2:** Solutions with other libraries is welcome.

Comment: It would help if you indicated what platform this is for.  Or do you need it to be cross-platform?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the CImg::display(); method ? It just display your image in an interactive viewer, just as Matlab does with imagesc.

```
CImg<double> matrix(200,200);  // Assume this is your matrix data.
matrix.display("My Matrix");
```

Comment: Should I construct my matrix as CImg<double> type and can how can I convert my 2D double matrix to CImg<double> type matrix?

Comment: Depending on how your matrix data are stored. If you want to export it from Matlab, you may use the [dlmwrite](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) command, then import it to CImg (CImg knows how to read .dlm files).

Comment: İt is a matrix at m C++ code and its type is not CImg<double> as well. If you help about it it will be good.

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods for [constructing a Cimg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a24f3b43daa4444b94a973c2c3fff82c5) is from a memory buffer of values, where the value type is templated.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you explain more what you mean with that link? Let's assume that I have a variable named myMatrix (is a two dimensional matrix) and I filled it with double valuables. Can you write a piece of code how can I show it as an image as like Matlab?

Comment: Basically, you can do : CImg<> mat(100,100); cimg_forXY(mat,x,y) mat(x,y) = myMatrix[y][x];